# How to focus on file dialog box using Selenium to pick a file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wish to upload a file into a specific site I'm supposed to test.
How do I make the Selenium focus on the file dialog box?

When I try to send keyboard strokes - the strokes go to the site, and not to the new file dialog box.

**My code:**

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(browser);       
    builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    builder.sendKeys(keyBoardText).perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned that I can only use Actions.sendKeys() on a WebElement that I clicked on.

If I just need to click on the keyboard - I need to use the Robot object.

This code solved my issue:

```
    softAsserter = new SoftAsserter(testParameters);
    String textToType = testParameters.get("actionData");
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        for (char c : textToType.toCharArray()) {
            int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
            if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
                logger.error("Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
            }
            else {
                try {
                    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                   if (c=='_') {
                       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                   }
                   if (c==':') {
                       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to upload files.
Usually we upload the files without clicking on upload button on the website and open the files dialog.

In Selenium you need to find the upload element on the site page and send the local file location.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Upload Element")).sendKeys("PathToFile");
```

If you prefer to open the file dialog then I suggest you to use Robot framework.

```
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

But please mind, when you use the Robot framework you need to release the mouse cuz it holds the mouse cursor.

[Here](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html) you can find different ways for uploading files.